# Change nonth from 8 to 08 in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the month year from date that is in database.

I used the following query to get the date. But the formatting is not as I require. Due to this my query is not giving the result which I am expecting.

```
select top 3 datepart(yyyy, cia.DateCreated) as YYyy, datepart(mm, cia.DateCreated) as mm,

    case when (datepart(mm, cia.DateCreated) < 10) then      
        cast(concat('0',datepart(mm, cia.DateCreated)) as varchar) 
    else 
        datepart(mm, cia.DateCreated)
    end as Months

   from v_AuthListInfo cia
```

I am getting the month values as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 but I need the value like 01, 02, 03, 04 ...

I tried to use DatePart, Cast and Concatinate function but still I am getting the data like 1, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: You would normally do that sort of formatting in your front end, not the database.

Comment: @DaleK I need to use it in other query. Or may be SSRS report.

Comment: SSRS report is the perfect place to do such formatting. (SSRS *IS* a front end).

Comment: The reason your approach didn't work is because you had different datatypes in your case expression branches. If you case all the dateparts to varchar it works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `right()` function

```
RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(MONTH(cia.DateCreated)), 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in function `format()`:

```
format(month(cia.DateCreated), '00')
```

If you want to use the `right()` method, I would suggest:

```
right(concat('00', month(cia.DateCreated)), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's general approach how to pad with ceratin character:

```
right(@padding + cast(@stringToPad as varchar), 2)
```

where `@padding` consists of characters you want to use and its length has to be the desired length, so in your case it would be `00`.

`@stringToPad` is string you want to extend, in your case `cast(month(cia.DateCreated) as varchar)`.

So finally, giving an example, it would look like:

```
select right('00' + cast(1 as varchar), 2)
```